# Update table cell value from input text

Tags: php, html

This is how my table looks like:

```
<table id="mytable" border="2" style= "background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
      <thead style= "background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Goal</th>
          <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
         if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
              $num_rows = 0;
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $num_rows++;
                  
                  echo
                  "<tr>
                  <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                  <td><input type='text' name='goal' id='goal' value='{$row['goal']}'></td>
                  <td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to update the goal?');\" href='updategoal.php?id={$row['id']}&goal={$row['goal']}' class='aR'>Update goal</a></td>
                  </tr>";
              }
              /*freeresultset*/
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the `updategoal.php` is here:

```
<?php

include "dbase.php"; // Using database connection file here

$unsafe_goal = $_GET['goal'];
$safe_goal = (int)$unsafe_goal;

$unsafe_variable = $_GET['id'];
$safe_variable = (int)$unsafe_variable;

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE goals SET goal = $safe_goal WHERE id = $safe_variable");

if($sql)
{
    mysqli_close($link); // Close connection
    header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit;   
}
else
{
    echo "Error deleting record"; // display error message if not updated
}
?>
```

When hovering the mouse over the `<a Update goal /a>`, the url shows me something like: https://example.com/updategoal.php?id=1&goal=10, so it doesn't change the goal to what I typed in the input text, it just add the same goal as it was before. Any tips?

Comment: There is no point of downvoting the question, unless you people are commenting what is wrong with the question. In that way we new people can learn to formulate our questions better.

Answer (score -1):

It took me quite a while to understand what you're asking but I think I got it. So, what happens is that the link gets created once the page is loaded and keeps the same value, even if you update the goal input field. You need some kind of js script to check when the input value has changed and then change the link accordingly.

Edit: I'd also suggest working with classes instead of ids in your table. Here's an example that works as expected

```
<table id="mytable" border="2" style= "background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead style= "background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Goal</th>
      <th>Update</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>145</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='goal' class='goal' value='2' onkeyup='changeLink(this)'></td>
      <td><a href='updategoal.php?id=145&goal=2' class='aR'>Update goal</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>146</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='goal' class='goal' value='0' onkeyup='changeLink(this)'></td>
      <td><a href='updategoal.php?id=146&goal=0' class='aR'>Update goal</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

function changeLink(input){
  var newGoal = input.value;
  var td = input.parentElement;
  var link_td = td.nextElementSibling;
  var updateLink = link_td.querySelector('a');
  var oldLink = updateLink.href;
  updateLink.href=oldLink.substring(0, oldLink.length-1)+newGoal;
  console.log(updateLink);  
}
```

https://codepen.io/cst90/pen/zYqOEzL

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Contributions are welcome, but when a question is unclear or doesn't have enough details, it's usually better to ask for more information in the comments first, rather than taking a guess and posting an answer that might not actually be what they want :) Take a look at the "Answer well-asked questions" section in ["How do I write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This will help you identify questions where your efforts can be more helpful both to the OP and other users with similar questions :)

Comment: You're right, I should have posted a comment first, I'm still learning how this all works, so I didn't know that when I posted the answer. Later I found out I could post comments, but my points are still not enough for me to do this, so this option is locked for me...